# Resize strip.background to match strip.text in ggplot facet_wrap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I am attempting to make lots of "small multiples" plots.

(Aside/Background) I have too many facets to display in a single plot so I need to manually subset them up into separate plots. I was hoping I could just pass the desired `ncol` and `nrow` to `facet_wrap` and it would make as many as I needed.  That is not the case.

Because I have so many facets, space is at a premium.  So, I wanted to reduce the size of the facet labels.  Easy enough to reduce the `strip.text` font size, but sadly the `strip.background` rectangle does not size with the font nor does it provide sizing parameters (apart from border size).  Setting it to `element_blank()` doesn't actually remove the space that is set aside for it, it just makes the same space transparent.

MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
xcat = rep(1:10, 1000)
yvalue1 = rep(runif(10,5,7),1000)
yvalue2 = rep(runif(10,4,6),1000)
id = rep(1:1000,each=10)

df = data.frame(id,xcat,yvalue1,yvalue2)

for(i in seq(1, length(unique(df$id)), by=100)){
  print(
    ggplot(subset(df, id %in% unique(df$id)[i:(i+99)]), aes(x=xcat)) +
      annotate("line", y=yvalue1, x=xcat, colour="cornflowerblue") + 
      annotate("line", y=yvalue2, x=xcat, colour="grey20") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=5),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size=5),
            strip.text = element_text(size=5)) +
      facet_wrap(~id, ncol=10, nrow=10) + 
      expand_limits(y=0))
}
```

[image: example image with default grey strip.background]

Any ideas on how I could reduce the height of that strip.background so that it doesn't take up so much space?  Ideally it would be sized to the exact height of the id text.

As a bonus, how to reduce the spacing between facets?  (Is there a setting in facet_wrap that I'm missing?)

It also takes a REALLY long time to render in RStudio with `facet_wrap` (without facet_wrap it is much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you want is achievable modifying the `grobs` created by `ggplot`. The process is somewhat messy and bound to need some manual fine tuning:

Setting aside the loop, that is uninfluential on the problem, we can start by reducing the spacing between facet. That is easily done by adding the `panel.spacing` argument to the `theme`.

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- ggplot(subset(df, id %in% unique(df$id)[1:(100)]), aes(x=xcat)) +
  annotate("line", y=yvalue1, x=xcat, colour="cornflowerblue") + 
  annotate("line", y=yvalue2, x=xcat, colour="grey20") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5),
        strip.text = element_text(size=5),
        panel.spacing = unit(.5, 'pt')) +
  facet_wrap(~id, ncol=10, nrow=10) +
  expand_limits(y=0)
```

We then have to generate a ggplot2 plot grob. This create a list of individual elements composing the plot.

```
g <- ggplotGrob(d)

head(g, 5)
# TableGrob (5 x 43) "layout": 13 grobs
#    z         cells        name                                    grob
# 1  3 ( 5- 5, 4- 4)  axis-t-1-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 2  3 ( 5- 5, 8- 8)  axis-t-2-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 3  3 ( 5- 5,12-12)  axis-t-3-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 4  3 ( 5- 5,16-16)  axis-t-4-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 5  3 ( 5- 5,20-20)  axis-t-5-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 6  3 ( 5- 5,24-24)  axis-t-6-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 7  3 ( 5- 5,28-28)  axis-t-7-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 8  3 ( 5- 5,32-32)  axis-t-8-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 9  3 ( 5- 5,36-36)  axis-t-9-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 10 3 ( 5- 5,40-40) axis-t-10-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 11 4 ( 4- 4, 4-40)      xlab-t                          zeroGrob[NULL]
# 12 8 ( 3- 3, 4-40)    subtitle zeroGrob[plot.subtitle..zeroGrob.77669]
# 13 9 ( 2- 2, 4-40)       title    zeroGrob[plot.title..zeroGrob.77668]
```

Our objective is then to find and fix the height of the ones relative to the strips.

```
for(i in 1:length(g$grobs)) {
  if(g$grobs[[i]]$name == 'strip') g$grobs[[i]]$heights <- unit(5, 'points')
}
```

Unfortunately the `strip` `grobs` are also affected by the different `heights` the the main plot is divided into, so we have to reduce that ones also. I haven't found a way to identify programmatically which heights refers to the strip, but inspecting `g$heights`  is quite fast to figure out which we need.

```
g$heights
# [1] 5.5pt               0cm                 0cm                 0cm                 0cm                
# [6] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [11] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [16] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [21] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [26] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [31] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [36] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [41] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [46] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0cm                 0.5pt               0cm                
# [51] 0.518897450532725cm 1null               0.306264269406393cm 1grobheight         0cm                
# [56] 5.5pt       

strip_grob_position <- seq(6, length(g$heights) - 5, 5)
for(i in strip_grob_position) {
  g$heights[[i]] = unit(.05, 'cm')
}
```

We can finally draw the result:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

I am not an expert at all in the subject, so I may have said or explained something wrongly or inaccurately. Moreover there may be better (and simpler and more ggplot-ish) ways to obtain the result.

Comment: Awesome!  I followed the whole thing up to that last part.  `panel.spacing` and `g$heights` for just the strips makes sense.  But it wasn't clear to me that the final heights you changed were for the individual plot areas until I plotted the intermediate result and saw the space between the strips and the plots.  How did you choose .05 cm as the appropriate unit?

Comment: It just seemed a sensible value, the hard part is indeed to find the right one. Not sure why, but I have been unable to change from 'cm' to any other unit, such as 'pt', as it's usually the case with `unit()`

Answer (score 4):

According to [Hadley](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2464), there's now a simpler solution I've provided an example with simpler code for the benefit of anyone else stumbling upon this answer. The key is to set margin = margin() whenever you set the text size.

```
set.seed(2112)
# dataframe with two groups
df <- data.frame(group1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 300, replace = TRUE),
    group2 = sample(1:5, size = 300, replace = TRUE),
    x = rnorm(300), y = rnorm(300))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(group1 ~ group2) +
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 4, margin = margin()),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 20, margin = margin()))
```