# The circle plot is complete on large screens but cuts off on small screens

Tags: r, ggplot2

The circle plot appears well on larger screens like laptops, but when viewed on smaller screens like mobile devices, some circle points are not fully displayed; they are cut off, resulting in only half of the circle being visible. How can I address this issue to ensure the entire circle is visible on smaller screens?

```r
R_code<-
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
last4Months <- read_csv("E:/WORK/NOVEMBER/05.11.23(Problem solve)/last4Months.csv")
last4Months$WeekDay <- as.factor(last4Months$WeekDay)

ggplot(data = last4Months, mapping = aes_string(x = colnames(last4Months)[1], y = colnames(last4Months)[4])) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Month), size = 1.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = DayNr, color = Month), alpha=1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(~WeekDay, ncol = 3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1)), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1)), 
    legend.position = "top",
  ) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 30), color = "none")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/281Kh.png)

I try this code but it's not work for me.

```r
R_code<-
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
last4Months <- read_csv("E:/WORK/NOVEMBER/05.11.23(Problem solve)/last4Months.csv")
last4Months$WeekDay <- as.factor(last4Months$WeekDay)

ggplot(data = last4Months, mapping = aes_string(x = colnames(last4Months)[1], y = colnames(last4Months)[4])) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Month), size = 1.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = DayNr, color = Month), alpha=1/3) + 
  facet_wrap(~WeekDay, ncol = 3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1)), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1)), 
    legend.position = "top",
  ) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 30), color = "none")
```

Comment: `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` It might also help to change your plot sizes, eg by shrinking the facet headers like in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086847/resize-strip-background-to-match-strip-text-in-ggplot-facet-wrap